# Database design for timetable in mysql

Tags: mysql, database-design, java, application-design

I have to make a web application in java. The web application is like a online appointment book.

Everyday of the week has 1 column with times from 9.00am to 10.00pm (only full hours).

I already created the user table in the db where I save password and username, but how do I save all the timedates and a little description?

One of my fellow student told me to make 1 table for each day, with 1 column for each date, like 9.00am, 10.00am ..., I'm not sure if that is really the best solution.

I hope you understand what I mean, if not please tell me.

Comment: ,Can you edit your question again. what actually want to ask. It's not clear .

Answer (score 0):

You should have a single table called appointments with at least the following fields "AppointmentDateTimeStart", "AppointmentDateTimeEnd", "AppointmentSubject", "AppointmentDescription".  You may need to add other fields to best suit your application, such as a userID, private, deleted, AllDay or whatever else you need.  Maybe express the DateTimeEnd as a duration in minutes?  Whatever works for you.

You absolutely should not create a table that looks like a spreadsheet, the design is rigid.  Imagine that you needed appointments at the half hour or lasted longer than a single hour.  Yes, at the moment the business might say that never happens, but trust me, they will change their mind later when they realize that the design specifications they gave you only cover the common or expected use case.

Use application logic to prevent people from putting appointments outside of business hours, this will give greater flexibility.

Comment: thank you very much, thats exactly what i was looking for.